# load CSV into hidden elements once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to load a CSV file just once on page load - that way the client can manipulate the rows from the CSV quickly.

`$line` contains array like:

```
[0] => Array
(
    [0] => Australia
    [1] =>  Vic
    [2] =>  Tech
    [3] =>  East
)

[1] => Array
(
    [0] => Australia
    [1] =>  Vic
    [2] =>  Tech
    [3] =>  West
)

[2] => Array
(
    [0] => England
    [1] =>  Manchester
    [2] =>  Tech
    [3] =>  North
)
```

So in php top of the script I have

```
foreach ($line as $row) {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="hideCountries[]" value="'. $row. '">';                 
}
```

That works fine to create hidden elements that look like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hideCountries[]" value="Array">
```

So the question is how do I then assign the arrays in these hidden elements to a drop down list.
So I want drop downs that will look like

```
Country | State | Dept | Pos
-------------------------------
Aus      Vic     Tech   East
Aus      Vic     Tech   West
Eng      Manch   Tech   North
```

Using these drop downs, within jquery I would then like to use onChange event to then filter the list based on any combination of selections the user has made.

Ie, When they click "Aus" in the first drop down, the filter should remove "England" from the list and you should only see the first two rows above.
If they then select "East" from the "Pos" dropdown, then the list will filter further and only show the first row , where Country=Aus and Pos=East.

Is that possible in this structure of using hidden arrays, if so, how can I go about loading the drop downs initially with these hidden values, and then further filtering the list using jquery ?

If not possible, what other options do I have to load the data and then use js/jquery to manipulate?

Comment: sound like chain select to me, one of the example would be http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained, all you have to do is to populate the class name base on your list. try do more exploration and show some codes, not that difficult

Comment: it looks like chain has an order to it - ie, first you select dd1, then it populates dd2 and so on. I need more flexibility - i need to be able to select ANY dd and have the other ones filter out unwanted items.

Comment: you checked datatable out?

Comment: haven't used those before but looks very promising, thx